# How to make Client run always (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

So I finally managed to make my own discord Client and now I have a question - *can I run it **always?*** Like I do not have to start program every time to make my Client work, it works always and always responds on events. Any ways to do that?

Comment: If you mean it runs as soon as you start your computer, then there are some options depending on your OS. If you mean run it 24/7, then you will have to look at a hosting solution, or have your own hardware that will run the bot (like a Raspberry Pi).

Comment: @Benjin So I like need to run code on server-host or something?

Comment: The code has to run somewhere for your bot to be online.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make your Discord Bot always active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388307/how-to-make-your-discord-bot-always-active)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either package the project with tools like [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) or [build a docker container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) or alternatively add a [systemd unit file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) and hook your script into the autostart of your desired system. This all depends on your current knowledge and skills.

Comment: Is it something you can host online ? If it is then you could use pythonanywhere

Answer (score 0):

You should search for the hosting solutions, but for now, you can watch the Tech With Tim  [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPvg9bndP1U&t=733s) which would give you an idea.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).